List of abbreviations does not work
As the title says, my list of abbreviations is not displayed. My problem is that the whole thing comes from a template and I am quite sure that I have copied everything correctly. It works in the template.
The only important thing is that the directory does not work. (I have something like a table directory at the end of the text, but it is not displayed, the rest works)
In the Preamble we use this
\usepackage[%
    xindy,% xindy zum Indexieren verwenden
    acronym,% Separates Akronym-Verzeichnis
    nopostdot,% Kein Punkt am Ende einer Beschreibung im Glossar
]{glossaries}%

% Glossare & Abkürzungsverzeichnis:

\makeglossaries
\input{TUM_Latex_Wiss-Arbeiten/200805_TUM_LaTex_Vorlage_Wissenschaftliche Arbeit/Abkuerzungen.tex}
\setacronymstyle{short-long}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\@glsdotsep}
\setlength{\@glsdotsep}{\@dotsep em}
\newcommand*{\glsdotfill}{\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ \@glsdotsep{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother

\newglossarystyle{WissenschaftlicheArbeiten}{%
  \setglossarystyle{index}%

  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{\vspace{.75em}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{##1}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
     \item\glsentryitem{##1}\glstreenamefmt{\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}%
     \ifglshassymbol{##1}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##1})}{}%
     \space-\space\glossentrydesc{##1}\glsdotfill\glspostdescription\space ##2%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
    \item\glstreenamefmt{\textbf{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont\enskip\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}}\vspace{.3em}}%
}

\setglossarystyle{WissenschaftlicheArbeiten}

There is a own .tex file named Abkuerzungen.tex which looks like this:
% A
\newacronym{abk}{Abk.}{Abkürzungen}
\newacronym{a}{A}{Fläche}
\newacronym{ak}{a}{tiefster Punkt der Dreiecksöffnung}
\newacronym{al}{$\alpha$}{Halber Öffnungswinkel}
% B
\newacronym{bez}{Bez.}{Bezeichnung}
\newacronym{b}{b}{Breite}
\newacronym{bsp}{Bsp.}{Beispiel}
...

In the text it looks like xy does this and you can call the Easter buny with this \gls{fr} and this \gls{re}, which leads to this text, which is fine.

now we finaly come to my problem
with this code \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis]their should be this 
Instead nothing happens. Do you have any idea what could be the reason for this?

Please extend your code to a full but minimal example ofhters can copy and test as is.

Have you run makeglossaries? See this answer

@DaiBowen I use ovearlef so it is a bit compilcated to run a command.  Overleaf Glossaries
I tried it on textmakers but at the moment I see no diffrence. Does It made a diffrent, that all \newacronym{...}{....}{.....}are in an own document

@daleif this would be a hell of a template sorry the Link is german but it is the one "Wissenschaftliche Arbeit" I swear I use it like it is used their

Overleaf should run makeglossaries automatically. In that case my best bet would be an error, somewhere in the document, most of which we can't see right now. Is there anything in the log (make sure to look for the very first error there)? Try making a copy of the project, remove as much content as possible, remove packages, switch to a standard class like article, if you can get something short enough to post here, we're more likely to be able to help.

You should be able to turn this into a 20 line self-contained minimal working example (MWE).  Then we'll be able to see what's going wrong (and you might find the answer in that process as well).

DId you find anything? Is your main tex file in the project root?

@DaiBowen I did find nothing. At the momet it works in another projekt with the same code and I can't tell you why. Yes project root was correct
